# Mouseup event conflict with visibility toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I've created a function that toggles a menu based on its' visibility. I also assigned a mouseup event to the document where the menu closes if the user clicks anywhere outside of it. The problem is when the `mouseup` event listener is added for the `document` the toggle no longer works. The visibility test: `$menu.is(":visible");` returns `false` despite the menu being in plain sight. What's going on here?

```js
$(function() {
  var $toggleMenu = $(".toggle-menu"),
      $menu = $(".menu");
    
  $toggleMenu.on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    toggleUserMenu();
  });
  
  $(document).on("mouseup", function (e) {
      
    if (!$menu.is(e.target) && $menu.has(e.target).length === 0) {
      $menu.hide();
    }
  });

  function toggleUserMenu() {
    var menuIsVisible = $menu.is(":visible");

    if (menuIsVisible) {
   $menu.hide();
 } else {
      $menu.show();
 }
  }
});
```

```css
.toggle-menu {
  color: #444;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="" class="toggle-menu">Toggle Menu</a>

<div class="menu">
  <a href="#" class="menu-item">Menu Item 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item">Menu Item 2</a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item">Menu Item 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: you code for hide/show work twice.

Comment: The latest version of Chrome

Comment: problem is not chrome, toggleUserMenu run after you hide menu on  $(document).on("mouseup", function (e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution can be by preventing the `mouseup` in the conflicting area to bubble up.

```
$(function() {
  var $toggleMenu = $(".toggle-menu"),
      $menu = $(".menu");

  $toggleMenu.on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    toggleUserMenu();
  });

  $toggleMenu.on("mouseup", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  $(document).on("mouseup", function (e) {

    if (!$menu.is(e.target) && $menu.has(e.target).length === 0) {
      $menu.hide();
    }
  });

  function toggleUserMenu() {
    var menuIsVisible = $menu.is(":visible");
console.log(menuIsVisible);
    if (menuIsVisible) {
      $menu.hide();
    } else {
      $menu.show();
    }
  }
});
```

---

```
  $toggleMenu.on("mouseup", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

This will catch the `mouseup` that is fired along with the `click` on Toggle Button and stops it from bubbling up to `document`. `preventDefault()` doesn't have any specific purpose here, It came with your code that I copied :)

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eLpjqs4q/)

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I have to look into that. Never tried that feature.

Answer (score 0):

you run $menu.hide twice and it is problem.

```js
$(function() {
  var $toggleMenu = $(".toggle-menu"),
      $menu = $(".menu");
    
  $toggleMenu.on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    toggleUserMenu();
  });
  
  $(document).on("mouseup", function (e) {
    console.log("Event is still firing");
      
    if (!$menu.is(e.target) && $menu.has(e.target).length === 0) {
      //if you commment this the code work.
      // $menu.hide();
    }
});

  function toggleUserMenu() {
    var menuIsVisible = $menu.is(":visible");

    if (menuIsVisible) {
   $menu.hide();
 } else {
      $menu.show();
 }
  }
});
```

```css
.toggle-menu {
  color: #444;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="" class="toggle-menu">Toggle Menu</a>

<div class="menu">
  <a href="#" class="menu-item">Menu Item 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item">Menu Item 2</a>
  <a href="#" class="menu-item">Menu Item 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I still need that event listener for the `document` object. Otherwise the menu will stay on the screen. I need it to close if the `Toggle Menu` link is clicked **or** if the user clicks anywhere outside the menu/

Comment: each 'click' event have one 'mouseup' event. so your code for toggle menu run twice

Comment: Was trying to avoid flags to prevent from assigning any globals .